# Audio problems with some applications under Linux

Tags: linux, audio, opensuse, pipewire

I’m experiencing very annoying audio problems with some specific applications under Linux (I'm using openSUSE Tumbleweed). I've only noticed this with some games at the moment (but I’m not sure if this is related to games in particular or to a state of a heavier system load).

**Here is some system context:**

- Laptop with openSUSE Tumbleweed fully updated, KDE Plasma 5 with Wayland and Pipewire
- Issues occurring mainly with Wine apps, running from Bottles (flatpak)
- I noticed a less severe form even with some other games not using Wine, but still on flatpak

**Here are my problems and some additional info:**

- Since a few days ago, when running games in this environment, I’ve been experiencing some very annoying audio issues, as soon as the game is launched it seems to be working fine, but after a while, the sound starts to get buzzing/crackling. Sometimes just slightly, some other times the degradation goes on and completely mutes the audio.
- Even some games that do not require many system resources are giving me this problem.
- Audio in other applications is working nicely without any problem, both installed from the system repos (Browsers and VLC) and from flatpak (Kodi, Spotify for Linux).
- This trouble started a bit suddenly; I am not sure if it has something to do with a system update that may have changed my configuration, but before it started, I never had any kind of issue when running the same exact games.
- I tried to test this with plain pulseaudio instead of pipewire, but the problem remains.

**These issues are only present with the builtin speakers:**

- I have this problem only with one device, an AMD “Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller” sound card, when playing sound through the laptop speakers
- If I connect an external TV device through my laptop HDMI port (that uses another sound device, “Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio Controller”), the sound works fine
- If I connect wired earphones to the Jack port, the sound works fine
- If I use wireless Bluetooth earphones, the sound works fine

I'm not really sure, but I suspect that there is some specific configuration that I have to tweak in order to prevent this. But I don't know where exactly this problem is originating (pipewire? wireplumber? specific device configuration? some other place?).

Can somebody help me to better diagnose this, and finally find a solution?

If more info is needed, please ask and I'll provide it. Thanks!

Comment: I started a bounty, I need some help at least to gather reliable information and to diagnose and pinpoint the problem, before even trying to find a solution.

Comment: What's the kernel version?

Comment: @GChuf it's 6.7.1-1-default

Comment: Sounds like it has nothing to do with games or system load... Some people mentioned certain kernel versions didnt work for them (I think 6.6 was mentioned). No idea how to troubleshoot though ...

Comment: Which laptop model is it? Is the BIOS/UEFI fully updated?

Comment: @harrymc I have a Slimbook, it is a manufacturer that sells Linux machines. I have had this laptop for about 3 years, and these problems started about a month ago. And yes, the Bios firmware is updated.

Comment: If it's possible that the problem was caused by the 6.7.1-1 version, try perhaps to downgrade.

Comment: I have the same problem even with 6.6.x

Comment: @harrymc One thing that I noticed is that both my sound devices ("Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller" and "Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio Controller") are manufactured by AMD, but if I inspect with `hwinfo --sound`, I can see that they are both using `snd_hda_intel` driver. I have and AMD-only system. I'm not sure if before these problems occurred there was another driver in place.

Comment: You might be missing a driver, but I can't help with that. How likely is it that you had an automatic driver update?

Comment: @harrymc I will try to investigate more on opensuse specific places. I'm not really sure, but I think that it is unlikely. What is driving me mad is that everytime that I try to make a change in the whole stack (pipewire, pulseaudio, kernel, specific configs for frequency bitrates, quantum, etc ), nothing seem to improve, leaving me unable to pinpoint to exact problem  and keeping me  to blindingly try random stuff :/
Thanks for trying to help though.

Comment: I found (and lost) a source that claimed it worked in the first 6.7 version.

Comment: I also found something in the ArchLinux forums, maybe it is this one https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=291324 , but it is not applying in my case. I have this problem even with 6.7 (and 6.6 and 6.5 too, so it seems to be unrelated even to kernel probably...).
One thing that I noticed, but I don't know how to prove/measure it, is that this problem seems to be occurring when there is an heavier disk usage

Comment: Do you have 'iotop' command available? It can help you measure disk usage.